# When is it appropriate to refer to yourself by これ?

Tags: word-choice, usage, vocabulary, first-person-pronouns, pronouns

I have occasionally heard and read instances, where a person has referred to themselves as これ. My Japanese dictionary also lists "Me, I." as a definition of これ.

Now, this obviously isn't used as frequently as 私, 僕, etc., so it makes me wonder: When can it be used to refer to one's self? and Does it have any extra or particular meaning as such?

Thanks! :)

Comment: wwwjdic lists the use of これ to mean "I/myself" as *archaic*. I don't think I have ever heard or seen it used in that way. Are you sure you are not thinking of こちら (which is a fairly common and conveniently neutral way to refer to yourself when talking to a stranger)?

Comment: I've seen この俺 a few times, I wonder if it's related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a little bit more to what YOU said in his answer: in some Classical Japanese texts これ was indeed used as a first (and also second) person pronoun. It's not the most common first person pronoun in Classical Japanese (that would probably be われ), but it's a possible use, so maybe that's where your dictionary got that from.

The quote from 枕草子 (The Pillow Book) YOU referred to is probably the one which shows up in Daijirin:

> 殿上人なども「なほこれ一人は」などのたまふを

Don't ask me to translate that though. :)

Comment: Heh, almost every lines in that Pillow Book can be separate question to ask :D

Comment: Yeah. This one can probably feed three or four separate questions though. :(

Answer (score 4):

I think that would be おれ 「俺」, and actually most frequently used first person pronoun for males in Japan currently when speaking.

The one you found in dictionary might be from まくらそうし「枕草子」 at Middle Heian-Era (around 1000 Years ago) but I don't think that one is in used recently.

or [これ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/27360/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C/) or [こら](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/27288/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%82%89/) has another meaning like "Hey"

> これ,静かにしろ　 Hey, be quiet!

Note: これ has some sense like "Listen", "I say", but こら is stronger on expression about angriness, scolding.

ref:

- [http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/27360/m0u/これ/](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/27360/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C/)
- [http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/27288/m0u/こら/](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/27288/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%82%89/)

Comment: I think you wanted to say: most frequently used **for males**. :)

Comment: @YOU: no problems. I wasn't sure enough what you meant to edit myself.

Comment: "I, me" is indeed listed among the definitions of [これ](http://www.jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C&eng=&dict=edict&common=on), so I don't think the poster was confusing it with おれ at all.

Comment: I think you are mixing up これ and こら in your example.

Comment: @Amanda, Nope, both are valid, I will update references.

Comment: @YOU Oh hey, you're right.  I missed that definition in my dictionary.  Thanks, I've learned something new.

Comment: @Amanda, yeah, updated my post too.

Comment: do @you mean to say that こら is related to これ ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use こちら (the humble form of ここ) to refer to yourself (and your in-group). It's not exactly これ but it's close. I would say this is most often heard in the phrase こちらこそ, used after someone thanks you to say something along the lines of, "The pleasure was all mine."　See [definition #3](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E3%81%93%E3%81%A1%E3%82%89&enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=3), given as synonymous with 自分（たち）. I tend to use it in situations that are somewhere between casual and formal, like talking with a 先生 or someone older I don't know very well.

Comment: And more informally, こっち.  I (and plenty of my Japanese friends) use it all the time.

Comment: Oh yeah totally. I was thinking about it, and I think that こちら can be a replacement for これ in certain contexts, like こちらのほうがいい == これがいい to say, "This one is better."

Comment: こちら is the humble form of ここ ?