# What is the nuance of この + [first person pronoun]?

Tags: nuances, first-person-pronouns

For example, from the song Fare Well by L'Arc~en~Ciel:

> あなたは いつまでも この僕のこと 愛してくれたのかな

and countless examples from manga, like:

> だが このオレは 死なん...
>
> こんどは このオレが きさまを 滅ぼす
>
> このオレに 勝てるわけがない

My guess is that it この + first-person-pronoun is just emphasis, but is there anything more here?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/973/when-is-it-appropriate-to-refer-to-yourself-by.  It is better to add a link when you know a related question.

Comment: It **feels** like it singles out that particular person and adds emphasis, like you said. I don't think there's anything beyond this. So このおれ would be "I [and no one else]", and そのあなた would be "you [and no one else]". I've got nothing to back this up, unfortunately.

Comment: Like when Daffy Duck says "Not *THIS* little black duck!"?

Comment: let's say my name is あき and i use このあき to refer to myself.. does/n't it sound rude?

Comment: @Pacerier: Using your own name to refer to yourself is highly unusual (if you're a girl and trying to project a cutesy character you *might* be able to get away with it), so このあき would sound very strange.

Comment: @Derek oic. because i've heard it in an anime called Fullmetal Alchemist where there is this character always referring to himself as このえんヴぃ (えんヴぃ is his name) i thought that he was trying to let the listener think that he is great and mighty or whatsoever (because there's no way he was acting cute in that context)

Comment: @Pacerier: I'm not familiar with that series, but I think you've come to the right conclusion. この + [name] basically draws excessive attention to yourself. (Kind of like how the bad guys in some of those hero shows refer to themselves as おれ様, as in おれ様に勝てると思ってんのか？.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say nuance of ラルク song is different with other manga texts.

> あなたは いつまでも この僕のこと 愛してくれたのかな

この僕 in above sentence is more like こんな僕, kind of humble.

Will you ever love me even if I were such ...

But, other sentences on manga are trying to express himself superior

> だが このオレは 死なん...  No wonder, I won't die (such easily)
>
> こんどは このオレが きさまを 滅ぼす,  Remember!, this I will destroy/ruin you next time.
>
> このオレに 勝てるわけがない. You can never ever beat me for any reason!!!