# The meaning of この+own personal name

Tags: grammar, meaning, manga, anime

One of the villains of ジョジョの奇妙な冒険, Dio, frequently refers to himself as「このディオ」 ([to the point it became a meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/it-was-me-dio)).

What's the meaning of this grammar: この+own personal name? Is it just emphasis? Or are there other nuances?

(might be related to [What is the nuance of この + [first person pronoun]?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/what-is-the-nuance-of-%e3%81%93%e3%81%ae-first-person-pronoun))

Answer (score 3):

Yes that's basically the same as この in この俺. この by itself just means "this". This type of この is an emphasis, and in this context it has a nuance of "nobody else but me/Dio", "of all others, me/Dio", etc. この俺 usually sounds more or less prideful, but この私 can be a humble and polite expression depending on the context.